# xaml container overflow hidden analog

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

Is there analogy for overlfow:hidden of html in xaml?
I just tryed different types of containers(grid, canvas, etc..) and still can't simulate that behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use something like:

```
<Grid Width="200" Height="100">       
  <Grid.Clip>
    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 200, 100"/>
  </Grid.Clip>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Unfortunally all elements but map inside grid are apply this borders as far as my main goal is to bound the map it doesn't work for me